# How do I sort such a format of Date Timestamp on Google Spreadsheet?

Tags: sorting, google-sheets

The image is the format of my Date Timestamp on gSpreadsheet. I have tried to sort it from earliest to latest date timestamp but it is not sorting well. Is there any ways to help me in this? Thank you, appreciate it.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try:

```
=SORT(A2:A; INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A; ",");;1); 0; INDEX(SPLIT(A2:A; " ");;2), 0)
```

where you can change 0 (desc) to 1 (asc)

Answer (score 0):

### Note!

You are using an invalid date format, time date should be a number and formated as date like so

[image]

### To sort as is:

> **Use this formula**

```
=QUERY(SORT({ A2:A, IF(A2:A="",,ArrayFormula(INDEX(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"GMT",""), ",")),,1)+INDEX(ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"GMT",""), ",")),,2)))}, 2,1), " Select Col1 ")
```

[image]

Comment: Hello, thank you for your help, it worked! Just a question to learn more because I don't know spreadsheet formula well.

I see that the output column has the same format as Timestamp column, so I am unsure what you mean by me having an invalid format? Based on the formula, is it right that what you did was first convert my Timestamp (STRING) column to Time Date number format and than reformat it to a correct Date format?

Comment: Yes right, `=ArrayFormula(SPLIT(SUBSTITUTE(A2:A,"GMT",""), ","))` to get date and time, and `sort` { the input | date time output [date+time] } , set sort column to `2` -"date time output [date+time]"- and `query` the `1` column. with "Select Col1"

Comment: I suggets you use the format i suggested form the beginning if you creatd the data

Comment: I see, I was actually converting date time epoch format using .strftime("%d %b %Y, %T") and input into the spreadsheet

Comment: If you can share the date time epoch format input in a comment, or ask another question, so you get the format right from the start.

Comment: an Example of the Date Time EPOCH is "1659792952". so what I did was format this EPOCH with python using this:

dt_obj = joined_date.strftime("%d %b %Y, %T"), and this dt_obj is what you see in the spreadsheet column TIMESTAMP

Comment: in this case, does the problem lies with the format I was using with strftime?

Comment: Your question can be asked in 2 parts **1) how to convert the input to date and time with the same formatting **2) how to sort the input as is, so we need to convert it and format and output it, or generate a helper column as i did in the answer to use it in the `SORT` function and output the original column. if you format the data properly form the start you can sort straight forward.